# Why ajax is returning value after its necessity?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "xyz", new AjaxOptions { 
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
    HttpMethod = "POST", 
    UpdateTargetId = "divDisplay", 
}))

{

<input type="submit" value="Edit" id="Edit" class="formBtn" onclick='return OpenErrorPopup()'/>

}


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function OpenErrorPopup() {

        debugger;
        var temp = false;

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: "/xyz/ChecLogin/",

            success: function (UserLoggedOn) {
                debugger;
                if (UserLoggedOn == "True") {
                    if (condition) {
                        temp = false;
                        return temp;
                    }
                    else {
                        temp = true;
                        return temp;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    temp = false;
                    return temp;
                }
            },

            error: function (err) {
                temp = false;
                return temp;
            }
        });        

        debugger;              
        return temp;

    }
</script>
```

Expected : First call openErrorPopup, execute ajax and then return the value dynamically.

Actual : Though openErrorPopup is called, it returns the temp value directly first to the `<input .... onclick=...>` and then executes the ajax.

I came to know ajax execution will be asynchronous. So I tried OnBegin event of ajax but thats not returning value. Kindly provide some solution on any of these two issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you make the ajax call on the same domain, you can instruct [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to be synchronous. Just pass "async: false" to the ajax options:

```
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        async:false,
        url: "/xyz/ChecLogin/",

        success: function (UserLoggedOn) { ...
```

and there is no need to return tmp from success and error callbacks, just initialize it.

Comment: don't. ever. ever. do. it. please. it'll "freeze" client's browser while your server will be processing request.

Comment: oh :( what could be the best solution?

Comment: @Alex: eek synchronous is the root of all evil. What if you page takes 10 seconds to load. You want to have a 'hanging' webpage?

Comment: or in case of bad browser - hanging browser.

Comment: there is not more than one line in ajax success function so probably it would not hang up the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Make this input `button` (or just always return false from OpenErrorPopup) and submit form  inside OpenErrorPopup via `$('form#xxx').submit()`.

Comment: what should be this 'form#xxx'?? should it be the value given in UpdateTargetId?? or the button's id?? because i tried with button id "Edit" but it dint work.

Comment: <form> which holds your submit button.